# Does Oozie support decision node to call either fork-join or single action node?

Tags: switch-statement, oozie, fork-join, oozie-workflow

I am trying to have a workflow where, based upon a variable, either the full fork-join runs or just a single action runs. I'm getting an error saying no fork for join to pair with. Is this supported? This is what I am doing:

```
<start to="path_decision"/>

<decision name="path_decision">
    <switch>
        <case to="fork-join-path">${some_var eq "foo"}</case>
        <default to="node1"/>
    <switch/>
<decision>

<fork name="fork-join-path>
    <path start="node1"/>
    <path start="node2"/>
</fork>

<action name="node1">
    <ok to="path_end_decision"/>
</action>

<action name="node2">
    <ok to="path_end_decision"/>
</action>

<decision name="path_end_decision">
    <switch>
        <case to="join_end>${some_var eq "foo"}</case>
        <default to="normal_end"/>
    </switch>
</decision>

<join name="join_end to="normal_end">

<action name="normal_end">
...clean up
</action>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example the following path looks valid:

`start`->`path_decision`->`fork-join-path`->`node1`->`path_end_decision`->`normal_end`

In this path you have a `fork` but you don't have a `join` which is not good. Oozie's forkjoin validator will find this and give you an error. It will not recognize that you added the same condition to `path_decision` and `path_end_decision`.

I would use `node1` and `node2` for the fork path. In this case you don't need the `path_end_decision` node, just go to `join_end` directly from `node1` and `node2`. For the non-join path I would go to a new `node3` from `path_decision` and to `normal_end` from there.

You also have a missing `"` at `join_end` but I hope it's only a typo.

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned: The above XML is just pseudocode but thanks about the missing '"'. I'll add that just be clear. But regarding the missing join, in 'path_end_decision', the first switch case goes to 'join_end' if 'some_var' equals "foo". Also that same requirement is needed to enter the fork path. So it seems like the fork node has a matching join node when it is needed. Or do you see something else?

Comment: Oozie's forkjoin validator will traverse all the paths, it will not recognize that you added the same condition to `path_decision` and `path_end_decison`. It will find a path with a fork but without a join and it will give you an error. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I was trying to avoid that, having to duplicate nodes (in this case node1=node3). In the actual workflow there are a fair amount of nodes in the forking process but it would be nice to be able to call each singly. Hence what I was trying to do but I was afraid the validator wouldn't pickup on this. 

I will defer to my other thought of making each action a separate sub-workflow so that they can be called separately but still be used in a fork-join. Will require a bit more xml-ing but not too bad I guess. Thanks